# Crystal lattice visualization software

Tags: linux, 3d

I'm looking for free (as in freedom) software for Linux that allows me to visualize simple crystal lattices and produce images such as this:

[image: NaCl structure]

Good features would be the ability to easily choose colors, add labels, select how many unit cells to show and add custom geometry like in the picture (faces). I should be able to create the structure from scratch in the software or using a well-documented non-proprietary file format. It shouldn't be too tied down to actual chemistry: I should be able to create "quasi-atoms", e.g. as stand-ins for molecules or whole classes of atoms.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking a look at the [IVisual](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IVisual) kernel for [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) - it is an port of the [Visual Python](http://vpython.org/) library to Jupyter - as such it lets you model 3D structures very flexibly from within your browser - there is even an animated structure very similar to what you are looking for implemented in less than 100 lines including the animation.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Flexible any 3D modelling not just crystals
- Non-propitiatory language
- Easily add labels, change colours, etc.
- Jupyter Notepads are stored in a plain text format and able to be exported to a number of other formats.
- [JupyterHub](http://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) would allow live models on a server.

### The AtomicSolid Example

[image]

### Update 2022

Things have moved on a long way in the 6 years since I wrote the above answer and looking into it again in response to a question from @Casimir below I found that the landscape has changed.

The IVisual mentioned above has been incorporated into [VPython-Jupyter](https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter) which means that it can be installed with `pip install vpython`

There is also the [Python Materials Genomics (pymatgen)](https://pymatgen.org/) package (written in python) and the [Crystal Toolkit](https://docs.crystaltoolkit.org/) which is written in Python on top of the Dash framework from [Plotly](https://plotly.com/).
These can be seen and used in an [online instance](https://next-gen.materialsproject.org/toolkit) available free *(this will run your calculations on a supercomputing cluster such as [NERSC](https://www.nersc.gov/), [OLCF](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/), [ALCF](https://www.alcf.anl.gov/) or [SDSC](https://www.sdsc.edu/) so will likely be much faster than running on your own machine)*.

Crystal Toolkit can be locally run from within a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) instance *needs a free Materials Project API key* or pymatgen & crystal toolkit can be pip installed and used within [Jupyter Lab](https://jupyter.org/) by following the instructions [here](https://docs.crystaltoolkit.org/jupyter).

### Citations

#### Materials Project

A. Jain*, S.P. Ong*, G. Hautier, W. Chen, W.D. Richards, S. Dacek, S. Cholia, D. Gunter, D. Skinner, G. Ceder, K.A. Persson (*=equal contributions)
The Materials Project: A materials genome approach to accelerating materials innovation
APL Materials, 2013, 1(1), 011002.
[doi:10.1063/1.4812323](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4812323)
[bibtex](https://materialsproject.org/static/docs/jain_ong2013.349ca3156250.bib)

#### Pymatgen open-source library

S. P. Ong, W. D. Richards, A. Jain, G. Hautier, M. Kocher, S. Cholia, D. Gunter, V. L. Chevrier, K. Persson, G. Ceder
Python Materials Genomics (pymatgen) : A Robust, Open-Source Python Library for Materials Analysis.
Computational Materials Science, 2013, 68, 314–319.
[doi:10.1016/j.commatsci.2012.10.028](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpe.3505)
[bibtex](https://materialsproject.org/static/docs/pymatgen.70fe034c9adc.bib)

#### Crystal Toolkit

S. P. Ong, W. D. Richards, A. Jain, G. Hautier, M. Kocher, S. Cholia, D. Gunter, V. L. Chevrier, K. Persson, G. Ceder
Python Materials Genomics (pymatgen) : A Robust, Open-Source Python Library for Materials Analysis.
Computational Materials Science, 2013, 68, 314–319.
[doi:10.1016/j.commatsci.2012.10.028](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.commatsci.2012.10.028)
[bibtex](https://materialsproject.org/static/docs/pymatgen.70fe034c9adc.bib)
[image: Online Crystal Toolkit]

Comment: Looks like development on IVisual stopped in 2016. Is the source code/docs still available somewhere? Couldn't find it on GitHub.

Comment: @Casimir - it looks like John has integrated his code into VPython-Jupyter https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter - the original source code is available on pypi on the page linked above.

Comment: @Casimir - Thank-you for the query - this led me to take a look at how things have moved on in the last few years and the answer was enormously. I have updated my answer to include the information that I found.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like a lot of people are trying to write software for this, but none of it is user-friendly or polished. In particular, documentation is usually very bad. Here is some of the software I have tried so far:

- [Jmol](http://www.jmol.org) has a [Crystal community](http://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/Crystal_Community) apparently, but there isn't any documentation on how to actually create and display crystals with it
- [Gcrystal](http://www.nongnu.org/gcrystal/) "is now part of the Gnome Chemistry Utils" but doesn't show up on [their website](http://www.nongnu.org/gchemutils/) (although they do have an entry for it on their [manuals](http://www.nongnu.org/gchemutils/manuals.html) page). I installed it from my distribution's repository (where it was still available as a standalone package under its own name) and tried it, but all I got was a blank screen even after adding atoms. It also had a tendency to segfault.
- [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/wiki/Main_Page) at least has [basic tutorials](http://avogadro.cc/wiki/Category:Tutorials) on its website, but the one on crystals is yet to be written. Nobody can write it, however, because [the edit link](http://avogadro.cc/w/index.php?title=Tutorials:Crystal_Unit_Cells&action=edit&redlink=1) takes you to a CloudFlare 404 page with no editing capabilities. I tried using it but the atoms kept randomly disappearing (all of them at once) so I didn't get far before becoming annoyed with it.

With the exception of Jmol, I only found the software through my distribution's package manager. None of the other applications show up in a Google search for "crystal visualization".

Answer (score 1):

There are to more free options (free more like a beer though):

- [VESTA](http://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/download.html)
- [Olex2](http://www.olexsys.org/)

They both go beyond just visualization and offer crystal structure analysis. Olex2 also is often being used for complete crystal structure refinement.